# How to use Texture Paint on two and more different objects at the same time

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I have two separated objects, the have to be separated. How can I paint on them at the same time? Their textures must perfectly match each other. I tried look for solution in internet but only what i found is that somebody wrote script to make it possible but he didn't share it. On picture two objects, on the right I started to paint and I want to tool continue paint on another object on the left.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a fairly simple process:

1. Create your two separate objects
2. Join them together as a single object using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
3. UV unwrap them so that their UVs don't overlap
4. Paint your textures
5. Select the mesh for one object while in edit mode and press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate it back into another object.

You can keep a copy of the join mesh around as well if you want to go back and tweak your textures.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if i have arleady painted object and i Will make another one, if i Will join them and UV unwarp, texture of painted object will be destroyed. And after join two object resolution of texture will be multiple less. That why I want to draw on separated objects. In future I Will create more objects next to painted.

Comment: @Pawel, you can always create a new unwrap and intermediate texture at a higher resolution and then bake to the old UV maps at whatever output resolution you want.